# Canon Print Driver Setup

Tags: macos, printing, settings, driver

We use Pharos and have two printer queues for our students to use.  One is black & white; the other is color.  For convenience, we want them to be able to print any document to the BW queue and pick it up at any of our printers, including color printers.  The problem is I cannot find a good PPD file to use for the BW queue.  Some Canon PPDs will force a job to print to BW, but they don't have a setting for duplex.  Other PPDs allow duplex, but don't force the document to come out greyscale.

The way the Mac package is created on Pharos utilizes lpadmin to add the printer.  But, I cannot find a list of options on lpadmin to see if one of those would default a driver to black and white.  If it did, then I could use one of the drivers that does color and just set it to greyscale.

The printers we use are all Canons.  The color models are: iR ADV C7055 and C7260.  The black and white models we use are: iR ADV 3245, 4251, 4245, and 6055.

The PPDs I have tried so far are: the universal and PS driver for the 4525, 5055, 6055, and 6075.  The downloaded files work for more than one model, though, so the files are PPD_v4.24_MACOSX, PPD_v4.26_MACOSX, PS_v04.13.00_Mac, UFRII_v10.14.00_Mac, and UFRII_v10.15.00_Mac.

Any suggestions or assistance would be appreciated.  If I have not provided enough info, please let me know.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) Can I suggest it may be worth [editing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/327620/edit) your question to include the exact models of printer(s) you're using? It may also be worth mentioning what PPDs you've already tried, otherwise you may get suggestions that don't really help. Finally, what version(s) of macOS are you running?

Comment: Thanks!  I added some additional info.  If that's not enough, I will try to add more.